# How to extend a module by extending a class that it is using?

Tags: inheritance, grammar, raku

**Some background:** I would like to extend [`JSON::Tiny`](https://github.com/moritz/json) to allow for more relaxed parsing of lists. This is similar to the `relaxed` flag for [`JSON::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) in Perl 5. Specifically, I would like to have the option of putting a comma at end of lists. For example, `{ "a" : 1, "b" : 2, }`. Note the comma after the `2`, this is not allowed by the normal JSON syntax specification (or `JSON::Tiny`).

By inspecting the [source code](https://github.com/moritz/json/blob/master/lib/JSON/Tiny.pm) it seems this could be as simple as extending one of the modules, [JSON::Tiny::Grammar](https://github.com/moritz/json/blob/master/lib/JSON/Tiny/Grammar.pm), that `JSON::Tiny` is using internally and then override two of its rules:

```
grammar JSON::Relaxed::Grammar is JSON::Tiny::Grammar {
    rule pairlist   { <pair> * %% \,            } # override this rule
    rule arraylist  {  <value> * %% [ \, ]        } #overide this rule
}
```

Note that the only modification to `JSON::Tiny::Grammar` is the 
introduction of `%%` operator instead of the `%` operator for the `pairlist` and `arraylist` rules.

Such an extension would allow for code
reuse. (The alternative of duplicating all the code in `JSON::Tiny` is a last resort.)

**Question**: The question is now how I should create my extension (called  `JSON::Relaxed`) without modifying or duplicating the code of `JSON::Tiny`? Here, is a sketch of the module I would like to write:

```
unit module JSON::Relaxed;
use v6;

use JSON::Tiny; # <-- since it is a module, I cannot extend it like a class

# a) export all the stuff that JSON::Tiny exports to the caller
# b) Somehow make JSON::Tiny use JSON::Relaxed::Grammar instead of JSON::Tiny::Grammar
```

What is the best way to achieve a) and b) in the comments above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pull in the grammar and actions separately like this:

```
use JSON::Tiny::Grammar;
use JSON::Tiny::Actions;
```

Then derive your own grammar just like in the question.

Using the resulting grammar and the existing Actions class, you'll end up with

```
JSON::Relaxed::Grammar.parse($input, :actions(JSON::Tiny::Actions)).ast
```

Note that in the META6.json [you can find the provides section](https://github.com/moritz/json/blob/master/META6.json#L8) that tells you exactly what you can `use`.

Since you want to take the original `to-json` from `JSON::Tiny`, you will have to export a `to-json` that forwards to the original. Here's code that does that:

```
sub to-json(|c) is export {
    use JSON::Tiny;
    to-json(|c);
}
```

This will make the symbols from `JSON::Tiny` available only inside the lexical scope of your `to-json` function, which will just take all its arguments and call the original `to-json` function with them.

Comment: Interesting idea! But wouldn't this mean that I will have to copy all the code in the `JSON::Tiny` module  into my `JSON::Relaxed` module? I was hoping  to avoid that part also..

Comment: @HåkonHægland No. [Grammars are classes](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars#Proto_regexes). You can use them as you would any other class. You will have to override the rules (class methods) for the grammar as well as for the Actions, if needed, but that's it. Other than that, they are classes.

Comment: @jjmerelo But `JSON::Tiny` is a module, it is not a grammar as far as I can see.

Comment: @HåkonHægland JSON::Tiny::Grammar is a class *and* a grammar. If it's public you can use and then override the methods you have said above. Point is, if you want to change a grammar, `use` it, inheriting from it, and then override the methods just as you would with any other class. You don't need to replicate all methods.

Comment: @jjmerelo Yes I understand that, but I think you miss my second issue of extending `JSON::Tiny` :) I would like to avoid duplicate the code in that module

Comment: @HåkonHægland the best way to do that would be to have parts of JSON::Tiny declared as roles, and not as whole classes. But the way it is now, I would create a clase derived from JSON::Tiny what would include the new grammar derived from JSON::Tiny::Grammar. I would have to dive  a bit more into the code to see if that's possible, but I would try to do that anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170801/discussion-between-jjmerelo-and-hakon-haegland).

Comment: Please check my edit, I added code to re-use the `to-json` sub from `JSON::Tiny`